# ShortDateFormat vs FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat?

Tags: delphi, datetime, delphi-xe4, log4d

In trying to get Log4D to compile in XE4, I was seeing

> [dcc32 Error] Log4D.pas(2139): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ShortDateFormat'

on this line:

```
SetOption(DateFormatOpt, ShortDateFormat);
```

A bit of googling led me to the solution of changing `ShortDateFormat` to `FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat`, which led to the following compiling code on XE4:

```
SetOption(DateFormatOpt, FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat);
```

However, I don't really understand *why* that fixes things why it's needed to specify `FormatSettings` since I already included `SysUtils` in my uses statement, and secondly, I'm not sure how to rewrite this line to continue to be backward compatible with the versions of Delphi this open source project already supports.

I suppose I could add an IFDEF around that parameter or line of code for whatever version of Delphi introduced `FormatSettings` - but I'm not even sure what version of Delphi that was, let alone whether that's a good or bad way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8):

The global `SysUtils.ShortDateFormat` was finally removed in XE3, see [`Global Variables`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Global_Variables).

In modern Delphi versions, the global `FormatSettings` variable record is also not recommended to use. Main reason is that it is not thread safe (which the old global `ShortDateFormat` also suffered from). You should define your own `TFormatSettings` variable that is consistent throughout your scope.

This will also make your code backwards compatible.

However, the way to initialize your `FormatSetting` record varies between Delphi versions.

On older versions (D7+) use:

```
GetLocaleFormatSettings(GetThreadLocale, FormatSettings);
```

And in newer versions (XE+):

```
FormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(GetThreadLocale); // Or one of the overloads
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix the compiler error:

- download a newer version of **jedi.inc** from https://github.com/project-jedi/jedi/blob/master/jedi.inc
- place the new jedi.inc in the Log4D source folder

and change line 2211 in Log4D.pas to

```
SetOption(DateFormatOpt, {$IFDEF DELPHIXE_UP}FormatSettings.{$ENDIF}ShortDateFormat);
```

(I have submitted some patch requests to the Log4D project admin)

Answer (score 2):

Based on my previous internet research (You ***can*** believe everything on the internet, can't you?), the old ShortDateFormat was deprecated started with Delphi XE. So, yes, you can IFDEF to solve the problem. That's what I do. However, according to Peter Johnson's [DelphiDabbler Blog](http://delphidabbler.blogspot.com/2014/02/when-did-delphi-language-first-support.html) TFormatSettings was introduced in Delphi 7, but I cannot confirm that.