# Is there a version of Async Pro which works with Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe3

I want to use **Async Pro** in my Delphi XE3. I found a version A407 on SourceForge, which seems to be the latest. When I try to install the runtime package A407_R100.bpl I get an error that a data length is longer than 2GB. When I fix this (with some guesswork) I get 4 other errors. I can try to fix those as well, but I'm afraid I will have to patch so much of the code that it won't work anymore.

Is there a version of **Async Pro** which works with XE3? Or at least clear and proven instructions how to patch the code?

**update**
[Here](http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/) I found an **AsyncPro** library which seems to be more up-to-date; at least the packages are named A407_*140.bpl instead of A407_*100.bpl. I still had a couple of errors in this part of the code in **AwAbsPd.pas**:

```
procedure InitializeUnit;
var
  TmpDateSeparator : char;
  TmpDateFormat : string[15];
  TmpDateTime : TDateTime;
begin
  {Set Unix days base}
  TmpDateFormat := ShortDateFormat;
  TmpDateSeparator := DateSeparator;
  DateSeparator := '/';
  ShortDateFormat := 'mm/dd/yyyy';
  TmpDateTime := StrToDateTime('01/01/1970');
  UnixDaysBase := Trunc(TmpDateTime);
  DateSeparator := TmpDateSeparator;
  ShortDateFormat := TmpDateFormat;
```

Although **SysUtils** is in the "uses" clause I got errors that `ShortDateFormat` and `DateSeparator` weren't defined. So I hard-coded them:

```
procedure InitializeUnit;
var
  TmpDateSeparator : char;
  TmpDateFormat : string[15];
  TmpDateTime : TDateTime;

// added stevenvh
var
  DateSeparator: char;
  ShortDateFormat: String;
  ShortTimeFormat: String;
// end addition

begin
  // added stevenvh
  DateSeparator := '-';
  ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy-mm-dd';
  ShortTimeFormat := 'HH:mm:ss';
  // end addition

  {Set Unix days base}
  TmpDateFormat := ShortDateFormat;
  TmpDateSeparator := DateSeparator;
  DateSeparator := '/';
  ShortDateFormat := 'mm/dd/yyyy';
  TmpDateTime := StrToDateTime('01/01/1970');
  UnixDaysBase := Trunc(TmpDateTime);
  DateSeparator := TmpDateSeparator;
  ShortDateFormat := TmpDateFormat;
```

Nearly there! Both runtime and designtime packages compile, but when I try to install the designtime package I get an error that "01/01/1970" is not a valid date. This is *not* an error in the above code, because it remains the same "01/01/1970" when I change the date in the code.

Turns out there is only 1 other file which includes "01/01/1970" as text, but this is a `.ocx` file, so I'm not sure how or even if I should patch this.

Comment: You have to provide a FormatSettings definition. And use the date/time functions with a FormatSettings overload. See [ShortDateFormat vs FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23707323/576719).

Comment: These version numbers (100 and 140) would suggest that they are for Delphi 3 and 6. Reaaaalllly old if that's the case ;-)

Comment: @Downvoter - When you downvote, please add a comment why you did, so that I can improve my question. Without comment your downvote doesn't mean a thing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat`, `FormatSettings.DateSeparator`, ... instead of introducing your own variables. That would be closest to the original.

A cleaner approach would be using the date/time functions with a formatsettings overload instead of temporarily changing the global formatsettings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't mean to have my not-so-clean patches to be permanent, I just wanted to see if they were the only problematic lines.

Comment: If you use `FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat`, ... then the code should work.

Answer (score 2):

Acording to this blog post:

http://blog.kassebaum.eu/?p=379

Async Proffesional is currently maintained by Roman Kassebaum but only for latest versions of RAD studio (both Delphi and CBuilder).

The menioned blog links to next source forge page:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/turbopowerasyncprofessionalnew/?source=navbar

Infromation on the page indicates that the project is closed and that it moved to github but no link is provided.

After doing some searching on GitHub I found the projects page

https://github.com/TurboPack/AsyncPro

Anyway since Roman Kassebaum is maintaing the project to be compatible with newest Delphi version it might not work for you.

So I strongly recomend you get in contact with Roman Kassebaum as he will best know which version should you use with your Delphi XE3 instalation or what needs to be fixed to make it compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The official AsyncPro version moved to GitHub. You can find it under [TurboPack](https://github.com/TurboPack/AsyncPro). It supports the latest Delphi and C++Builder version.

I also created a branch for XE3. You can find it under [TurboPack XE3](https://github.com/TurboPack-XE3/AsyncPro).

Comment: Are there any version documentation to be found? I also can't find a link to the TurboPack XE3 from the TurboPack.