# Delphi .proj file missing .dpk file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I recently got project in delphi which I need to rearange, I'm totally new in delphi so I'm searching my way in environment and language. Question, in my project group I have two files with .dproj extension, no corresponding .dpr file so when I try to load them I got msg:
"Canot open file xxxx.dpk, system cannot find the file specified"
Did the old programmer forgot to copy all files so I'm missing this, or is this some kind of file (.dproj) that I only add as a reference so I don't need to have corresponding .dpk or .dpr file??

Comment: Based on the fact that your are missing some DPK files it is quite possible that you are missing whole packages that contain some third part components in them. So first thing you should find out what third party components did the original author use. We might be able to help you ut with this if you provide the full name of the DPK files that are missing.

Comment: Hello SilverWarior, here's my situation, I got folder with many delphi form and source files. There are 5 .dproj files and only 3 of those have corresponding .dpr file (with same name). Two of them don't have coresponding .dpr file and I cannot load them in Rad studio throws me an error that I'm missing fileName.dpk file, "System cannot find the file specified". I also noticed that I'm missing AsyncPro components as well as TMSSoftware components but I assume I need to have those installed on my PC.

Comment: Then go and first install AsyncPro components on your computer. If you want to use latest version then check http://stackoverflow.com/a/29456189/3636228 where you can find link to the GitHub page dedicated to AsyncPro. As far as TMS Software components goes I strongly recomend you contact the original author and to get exact information of which component he used. You see TMS Software offer a whole bunch of components in various component packs. And since theese components are not free I guess you would want to buy only those that you actually need at first.

Comment: Just to gett better idea of what TMS Software actually offers check this page http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/products.asp?t=vclp You Will see that they offer quite a lot of different packages. So you definitly want to get only the one that you really need

Comment: One more question, in USES clause I have "Sockets" but I cannot find anything about what that is, where is that unit, is it some component from the Windows I need to add, or something external??

Comment: I don't remember in which unit did socket components reside in older versions of delphi but in Delphi XE these are located in `ScktComp.pas` that is of course if the original programer did use Socket components that ship with Delphi and not some third party socket library. Do you know in which Delphi version was the program originally developed?

Comment: Code is made in Delphi 10, and now I'm using XE8 currently. I suppose there will be no problems with that, or? It does not recognize Sockets, so I need to add this source file somehow or?

Comment: Delphi 10? There is no Delphi 10 version. Do you perhaps think Delphi 2010 instead?

Comment: It seems that socket components were moved into System.Win.ScktComp.pas file. So you would need to add that unit into uses section instead of Sockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .dpk file is the top level Pascal source file for a package. It is the package equivalent of an application project's .dpr file.

The original developer should have supplied it to you. Ask them to do so.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. So there is no any way that these .dproj files were used, like references work in .NET??

Comment: Your problem is not the .dproj file. Rather, the problem is that you are missing a source file. Delphi has nothing like .net references.